# Apache/PHP/JS  - Cannot change file permissions from 0644 to 0777

Tags: php, javascript, apache, file-upload, file-permissions

I'm using blueimp file uploader on my site (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

On my local machine (WAMP) uploaded files can easily be deleted.

On my online server (LAMP) the files cannot be deleted - 403 forbidden is returned. And all files' permissions are set to 0644.

I tried changing these manually via FileZilla (got 550 cannot change perms error). I also tried to do it via cPanel File Manager (the change just doesn't happen).

Does anyone have idea why this happens? Can desired permissions be set with PHP/JS before upload starts?

Why cannot I change permissions on a file I own? I own both the server and the file.

Thanks and sorry if question is not ideally formulated.

Answer (score 3):

With your local (Windows) based server - you are the administrator - you can delete any file.

On the Linux server, they are being uploaded as the webserver's owner (probably something like 'www-data') - but you don't have that permission. Setting the permissions from the PHP script would work, since they are run as the same user as the uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to do this? I tried changing mode from 'r' to 'w+' in fopen in the upload class (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/upload.class.php) without results. Any guidance or link is appreciated.

Comment: the 'fopen' is about writing the file (and since you are writing, it needs to be Writing). http://php.net/chmod will Change file Mode (changer the permissions). Do read up on the security issues about making the permissions too permissive. In the long term, it may be useful to have the scripts delete files itself that are no longer required.   Don't forget to mark up/accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry to ask further, but how would I apply this to file that is yet to be uploaded? I tried doing chmod immediately before move_uploaded_file but it didn't work.   chmod($uploaded_file, 777);move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);

Comment: You can't chmod a file that does not exist. Put it into place, then change the permissions on it.

Comment: this works for me: `move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path); chmod($file_path, 0777);`